Mulan-imitation cartoon
I'm searching for a cartoon with 10-20 years. It's basically an imitation of Mulan, but done in a way they wouldn't have to pay copyright.
An asian girl has to become a warrior (don't remember the reason). In the beginning, she is being made fun of by 3 male kids. Eventually she is able to cut a large roll of hay with her sword (which her father couldnt cut), and she goes to war. I don't remember what happens next, but she eventually finds a magic peacock that travels with her. There is a scene where she has a companion and the peacock cannot carry both. I also remember some sort of yin/yang talisman or medallion, that performs wishes. Eventually, she fights fire (against a stoned dragon or something?). I also remember a scene where she is looking into water and she sees the future or gets her hopes back up or something of the type.

Edit: I've found the book and VHS for sale! I just can't find any records on the internet that this actually existed! How do I find this on IMDB?

Not the movies i'm looking for:
The Secret of Mulan: youtube
The Legend of Mulan: youtube (part 1)
Hua Mulan: youtube
A Collection of Animated Family Movies - The Story of Mulan: youtube
Burbank Films - Mulan: youtube
Hua Mulan: youtube

Ok, so a friend of mine found this on Reddit:

Hello,
  I'm looking for an old animated movie, similar to this Mulan. It's from around the same period and it has about the same animation style.
  It's about a girl in ancient China, who after a series training obstacles becomes a warrior, just like Mulan, and goes on adventure to find a chinese dragon, who is being kept asleep with opium by the bad guys in a cave or some kind of a monastery up on a snowy mountain summit. She had a cricket or a lizard as a companion and she was carrying a coin or a medallion with her, who something to do with the four elements. When she rescued the dragon he melted the ice and the snow in order to remove the winter, bring back the spring to their lands and fill up the rivers again.

Where one of the answers was:

I know this one!
  It is this movie http://www.amazon.com/The-Legend-Mulan-Henk-Kreeftmeijer/dp/B00004CZGZ
  The only video I was able to find of it was of this swedish guy reviewing it
  


Holy crap, YES, it's this one! Thank you so much!
  edit:
  Whoo, found it - check out "mighty mulan phoenix games" on YouTube.

So, following the Amazon link, i found out that the above linked Legend of Mulan is the movie I was searching for. On YouTube, however, there are different names on its video. In fact, that movie can be seen here:



My VHS has this cover:

I've also updated the IMDB information.

Well, glad you found it, and thanks for doing all the legwork for Disney's lawyers. ;)

I've found not just one, but three non-Disney adaptations of the story of Hua Mulan.
The Secret of Mulan, where Mulan is (for some reason) an insect.



The Dutch production The Legend of Mulan



The Chinese production Hua Mulan




Do any of them match the OP's description? (3rd one looks kinda promising)

1st link doesnt work for me, so anyone else can try this one: https://youtu.be/Ra_whrbyIo4

Sadly, its not any of these movies. Ill edit my question so we can rule these out
